# Adding Tabs and static block content on product page

Tags: product, blocks, tabs

I've to add a new tab on product page and show some content from static block. Inside catalog.xml, I'm adding following code

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.info.details.shipping" as="product.info.details.shipping" template="catalog/product/view/tabs/additional.phtml">
<action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
<action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Shipping</value></action>
</block>
```

Which is working fine to show the tab aand content from `additional.phtml`.
 When I change block type to `cms/block`, it doesn't work. What is the proper way to add a new tab and show some content from static block there?

If I've to show content from static block, in that case also I need to create templates and write code there to print static blocks content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the method setBlockId and add the static block Identifier.

This code below was tested on Magento 1.9

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="cms/block" name="tab.new">
            <action method="addToParentGroup">
                <group>detailed_info</group>
            </action>
            <action method="setTitle" translate="value">
                <value>New Tab</value>
            </action>
            <action method="setBlockId">
                <block_id>static-block-id</block_id>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

[image]